# How do I translate my timer into the appropriate format?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a pomodoro timer chrome extension and I'm facing an issue where the code I pass for the timer's format from the background context (where the service workers are) into the popup doesn't seem to work. Instead of giving me a timer like `25:00`, where the minutes and seconds are separated and then decrementing, it decerements in seconds like this `1500`.

```js
// background.js

let timer = null;
let duration = 0;
let isPaused = false;

// Listens to when the cursor clicks on either the `Start` or `Reset` buttons.
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (request.action === 'startTimer') {
    duration = request.duration;
    isPaused = false;
    startTimer();
  } else if (request.action === 'pauseTimer') {
    isPaused = true;
  } else if (request.action === 'resumeTimer') {
    isPaused = false;
  } else if(request.action === 'resetTimer') {
    clearInterval(timer);
    duration = 0;
    isPaused = false;
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: 'updateTimer', duration: formatDuration(duration)});
  } else if (request.action === 'getDuration') {
    sendResponse({duration: formatDuration(duration)});
  }
});

function startTimer() {
  if (timer) {
    clearInterval(timer);
  }

  timer = setInterval(() => {
    if (!isPaused) {
      duration--;
      if (duration <= 0) {
        clearInterval(timer);
      }
      // Store the remaining duration
      chrome.storage.sync.set({remainingDuration: duration});
    }

    // Send a message to the popup to update the display
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: 'updateTimer', duration: duration});
  }, 1000);
}

function formatDuration(duration) {
    let minutes = Math.floor(duration / 60);
    let seconds = duration % 60;
    if (seconds < 10) {
      seconds = '0' + seconds;
    }
    return String(minutes) + ':' + String(seconds);
  }
```

```js
// popup.js

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let timerButton = document.getElementById('timerButton');
  let resetButton = document.getElementById('resetButton');
  let isTimerRunning = false;
  let isTimerPaused = false;

  // Get the current duration from the background script and display it
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: 'getDuration'}, (response) => {
    document.getElementById('timer').innerText = response.duration;
  });

  chrome.storage.sync.get(['isTimerRunning', 'isTimerPaused'], (data) => {
    isTimerRunning = data.isTimerRunning;
    isTimerPaused = data.isTimerPaused;
    if (isTimerRunning) {
      timerButton.textContent = isTimerPaused ? 'Resume' : 'Pause';
    }
  });

  timerButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (!isTimerRunning) {
      let duration = parseInt(document.getElementById('workDuration').value, 10);
      if (duration < 1) {
        alert('Work duration must be at least 1 minute.');
        return;
      }

      duration *= 60;
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: 'startTimer', duration: duration});
      timerButton.textContent = 'Pause';
      isTimerRunning = true;
    } else if (!isTimerPaused) {
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: 'pauseTimer'});
      timerButton.textContent = 'Resume';
      isTimerPaused = true;
    } else {
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: 'resumeTimer'});
      timerButton.textContent = 'Pause';
      isTimerPaused = false;
    }
    chrome.storage.sync.set({isTimerRunning: isTimerRunning, isTimerPaused: isTimerPaused});
  });

  resetButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: 'resetTimer'});
    timerButton.textContent = 'Start';
    isTimerRunning = false;
    isTimerPaused = false;
    // Store button state
    chrome.storage.sync.set({isTimerRunning: isTimerRunning, isTimerPaused: isTimerPaused});
  })

  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    if (request.action === 'updateTimer') {
      // Update the timer display
      document.getElementById('timer').innerText = request.duration;
    }
  });

  // Get the remaining duration from storage and display it
  chrome.storage.sync.get('remainingDuration', (data) => {
    document.getElementById('timer').innerText = data.remainingDuration;
  });
});
```

The `timer` is what should be updated to the `minutes:seconds` format but it doesn't

```html
// popup.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="popup.css">
    <title>Pomodoro Timer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Pomodoro Timer</h1>
    <div>
        <label for="workDuration">Work Duration (minutes):</label>
        <input type="number" id="workDuration" value="25" min="1">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="shortBreakDuration">Short Break Duration (minutes):</label>
        <input type="number" id="shortBreakDuration" value="5" min="1">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="longBreakDuration">Long Break Duration (minutes):</label>
        <input type="number" id="longBreakDuration" value="15" min="1">
      </div>
    <div id="Buttons">
        <button id="timerButton">Start</button>
        <button id="resetButton">Reset</button>
    </div>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    <div id="timer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a few places where #timer.innerText is set.  I would try logging them all, do they all show the wrong format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult for me to reproduce this but in your background.js file, when sending the update message, you are directly sending the duration value:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: 'updateTimer', duration: duration});
```

Instead, you should use the formatDuration function before sending the message:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: 'updateTimer', duration: formatDuration(duration)});
```

Additionally, in your popup.js file, when receiving the update message, make sure you are using the formatted duration to update the timer display:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (request.action === 'updateTimer') {
    document.getElementById('timer').innerText = request.duration;
  }
});
```

Comment: Yeah, turns out it was the `formatDuration` function having the duration argument within there. I didn't even realise you could do that. Thank you very much!